# XFile mock is not allowed as parametr of type XFile

Tags: unit-testing, dart, testing, mockito

I have a method that takes a single parameter, of type XFile.

```
  void add(XFile file) {
    // Add the new filename to the end of the list.
    _fileList.add(file);
    logger.v('Added ${file.path} to file list');

    if (_fileList.length == 4) {
      // Delete the file.
      _videoFileHelper.deleteSync(_fileList[0].path);
      _fileList.removeAt(0);
    }
  }
```

and in my test class I create a mock of the XFile class using annotations, like this:

```
@GenerateMocks([VideoFileHelper, XFile])
void main() {
```

I've run `build_runner` to generate the mocks too. `VideoFileHelper` works fine in my tests.

I can't get the MockXFile to work as a valid value to pass to `add()`, the linter in my editor (VSCode) thinks it's fine & doesn't flag any errors but when I run the test I get:

```
: Error: The argument type 'MockXFile' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'XFile'.
test/fileList_test.dart:31
- 'MockXFile' is from 'test/fileList_test.mocks.dart'.
test/fileList_test.mocks.dart:1
- 'XFile' is from 'package:cross_file/src/types/io.dart' ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cross_file-0.3.2/lib/src/types/io.dart').
package:cross_file/…/types/io.dart:1
    l.add(x);
          ^

Failed to load "/Users/stuart/Projects/third_eye/test/fileList_test.dart": Compilation failed for testPath=/Users/stuart/Projects/third_eye/test/fileList_test.dart
```

The generated mock file pulls in the XFile definition from `import 'package:cross_file/src/types/interface.dart' as _i3;` and defines the mock class with `class MockXFile extends _i1.Mock implements _i3.XFile {`

Comment: Is there any chance that you're using some other class also named `XFile`?  Can you inspect `fileList_test.mocks.dart` and provide the `import`s and the portion of the `MockXFile` definition that declares what types it `extends` and `implements`?

Comment: @jamesdlin I've added the extra info, you might be on to something there, I ust assumed that the XFile from the camera module was just re-exporting the one from cross-file, but maybe not. EDIT: I've followed it through and it does just export the one from cross_file.

Comment: I tried it and can reproduce it.  Seems weird.  It seems that Mockito might generate a different `import` for `XFile` in different circumstances; changing the `import` to `import 'package:cross_file/cross_file.dart' as _i3;` fixes it for me.  Sounds like a bug.

Comment: I've filed https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/issues/529 for you.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thank you for that, I've followed the report for updates.